# Manually creating Outlook signature

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

I am trying to create an Outlook signature manually (NOT via Outlook)

According to Microsoft Support (and other resources) i need to create a file (.txt, .rtf or .htm) in %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures

However if i add my file in that directory, the signature does not show up in Outlook.

If i create a signature via Outlook, no file gets created in the %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures directory

I am using a Dutch version of Office 2010 and Outlook account is an Exchange account.

Edit:

Can the path %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures where Outlook finds it signatures be changed? I have some ancient signature management software on my PC (For another user).

If i create a signature in Outlook shouldn't it show up in that same directory? Because it doesn't.

Comment: You usually have to create a .txt AND .rtf AND .htm versions of the signature.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Created the 3 files. Still not showing up in Outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking file access with ProcMon i found the location of the signatures.

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

Is incorrect on our system because of profile redirections in the GPO. I found the signatures in the following location:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\$REG_KEY_VALUE$
```

With:

```
$REG_KEY_VALUE$ = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\General\Signatures
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a custom directory configured for Outlook signatures. The registry key that specifies this directory for Outlook 2010 is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\General
```

Please check this key's `Signatures` value. In order to use the default AppData folder the value has to be `Signatures`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to deploy a default email signature in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2691977) :

- Close Outlook.
- Delete the First-Run value under the following key in the Windows registry:

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Setup

Note, x.0 depends on your version of Outlook:

```
Outlook 2013 = 15.0
Outlook 2010 = 14.0
Outlook 2007 = 12.0
```

- Add/deploy the signature files and folders you want to use for email signatures to the \Signatures folder under the user profile. This location varies, depending on your version of Windows.

> ```
> Windows Vista,Windows 7, or Windows 8
> %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
>
> Windows XP
> %userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures
> ```

- Create or locate the following key in the registry:

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common\MailSettings

or

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common\MailSettings
```

- Create the following value(s) under the MailSettings registry key:

> Name: NewSignature Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ Value: The name of signature to
>   use for new messages (see step 3 above for signature names)
>
> Name: ReplySignature Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ Value: The name of signature
>   to use for reply messages (see step 3 above for signature names)

- Start Outlook and open a new e-mail message.

The signature specified in the NewSignature registry value will automatically appear in the body of the message.

Comment: Thats the documentation i tried. I did not work. Signature does not show in Outlook

Comment: That is the process for assigning the *default* signature.

Comment: According to some other resources omitting the step where i create the NewSignature and ReplySignature keys would still install them as non-default signature. I tried both ways. Signatures do not show up in outlook at all. Is this because it is an Exchange acount? (Signatures stored on server-side?)